# How to validate Spring form:form's form:password with JQuery Validation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, spring-mvc, jquery-validate

I am unable to validate the spring for which have two password fields.

If i change from form:password to input type="password" it **starts working**, but then data does not gets bind with commandName, and i receive null in controller.

```
    <form:form action="changepas" commandName="mypwd" method="post" id="cngpwdform">
<div>
<table>
<tr><td>Current Password</td>
<td><form:password id="curPass" name="curPass" path="pwd" /></td>
</tr><tr>
<td>New Password <td>
<form:password id="newPassword" name="newPassword" path="nwpass" /></td>
</tr><tr>
<td><input type="submit" value="Change Password" /></td>
</tr>
</form:form>
```

Now we have this JQuery validation

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#cngpwdform").validate({
        rules : {
            'curPass' : {
                required : true
            },
            'newPassword' : {
                required : true
            }
        }

    });

});
```

Please tell me one thing.

I have few other forms which perfectly binds data with commandName and are like < form > < / form >  and i use < input > tags in them, works fine, but to add password fields i am getting null value in the controller.  Then to resolve this i have to use the < form : form > and for field i have to use < form : password > but then jQuery does not validates it.... Can you sens what could be wrong with this ?

Adding Generated HTML as asked by Sparky :
My God !! name attribute is appearing twice, once the name i had given and another the path name.

```
<form id="cngpwdform" action="changepas" method="post">
<div>
<table>
<tr>
<td>Current Password</td><td><input id="curPass" name="pwd" name="curPass" type="password" value=""/>
</td></tr>

<tr>
<td>New Password<td><input id="newPass" name="nwpass" name="newPass" type="password" value=""/>
</td></tr>

<tr>
<td><input type="submit" value="Change Password"/>

</td></tr>    

</form>
```

Comment: Show us the _rendered_ HTML as seen by the browser.  After all, that's what the JavaScript is really using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you try this:

```
<form:password id="curPass" name="curPass" path="curPass" />
```

If you view source on your rendered HTML and maybe put a break point in firebug for your jquery  validate function you will notice that the validate is not being fired.

Comment: So, for password field we need to have same name for path-name and html-name-attribute. Otherwise name is auto-generated by the name of path-name, Right ?

Comment: If you look at spring form tag docs, the path is a mandatory attribute and id is not. If you do not specify id or name, spring form tag will auto generate the id and name. This is true for all spring form fields and not just for password field.